# Postgres 9.4.7 INSERT INTO without ON CONFLICT

Tags: postgresql

I would really like to write a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO test_table (id, dt, amt)
VALUES(4, current_timestamp, 15)
ON CONFLICT (id)
DO UPDATE
    SET dt = VALUES(dt)
        amt = VALUES(amt)
```

The problem is, the version of Postgres I'm using (9.4.7) doesn't support the ON CONFLICT construct. Any ideas of how to achieve this without upgrading Postgres?

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL 9.4 doesn't have any built-in UPSERT (or MERGE) facility, and doing it efficiently in the face of concurrent use is very difficult.

[This article discusses the problem in useful detail.](http://www.depesz.com/2012/06/10/why-is-upsert-so-complicated/)

In general you must choose between two options:

- Individual insert/update operations in a retry loop; or
- Locking the table and doing batch merge

For complete solution read this 
[SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267417/how-to-upsert-merge-insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql)

Answer (score -1):

If you do it frequently. You can write a function to do it for you. 
You can do by two ways.

1. Check first then insert or update.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_test_table(int, timestamp, varchar)
    RETURNS int AS
    $BODY$
    BEGIN
        IF (EXISTS(SELECT id FROM test_table WHERE id = $1)) THEN
            UPDATE test_table SET dt = $2, amt = $3 WHERE id = $1;
            RETURN 2;
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO test_table (id, dt, amt) VALUES($1, $2, $3);
            RETURN 1;
        END IF;
        RETURN 0;
        END;
    $BODY$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

2. Use Exception:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_test_table(int, timestamp, varchar)
    RETURNS int AS
    $BODY$
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO test_table (id, dt, amt) VALUES($1, $2, $3);
        RETURN 1;
        EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN 
                BEGIN
                    UPDATE test_table SET dt = $2, amt = $3 WHERE id = $1;  
                    RETURN 2
                END;
    END;
    $BODY$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The second way maybe conflict with other unique constraint, so be careful.

Comment: Both solutions are not totally correct, because they are subject to race conditions. Consult the PostgreSQL wiki for a solution.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand clearly. Could you please help me explain more if you don't mind?

Comment: I mean the example in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING). The table could change between the first and the second SQL statement.